# Stripe iframe inside Elementor popup not working

Tags: wordpress, iframe, popup, elementor

On my WordPress website, I'm using Paid Membership Subscription (PMS) by Cozmoslabs, which supports Stripe Connect as a payment method. I also use Elementor. I created an Elementor popup that contains a PMS short code [pms-register], which instantiates an iframe for the Stripe payment form to collect the credit card information. In the popup, the iframe is there, but the div#root inside the body of the iframe is empty. The popup gets trigger upon click of a button.
If I put the same PMS short code on a page, the iframe with the credit card form shows correctly.
Any idea why the divs inside the iframe don't show in the popup?

Comment: The Elementor popup is probably a JavaScript/jQuery lightbox. Are there maybe security concerns with having a Stipe iframe included in the front end?